# Call multiple axios queries in a query to create a new object field

Tags: vue.js, axios

This is my first time asking a question on the forum for a problem, please be indulgent. Let me explain, I have created a Vuejs component that displays user data from an axios HTTP request to my server.

The user's information is grouped in an object with these fields:

- id: int
- email: string
- firstname: string
- secondname: string
- ...
- **dogs[]**

It's the last field of the object that I have a problem with. Indeed, my api returns the user's dog information in a dog object array. These dog objects can have a picture_serial_id which allows me to call another HTTP axios request to return the dog picture in base64.

So I make my first HTTP request and with its result, I browse all the elements of the dog object array of the response in order to make the second HTTP request which takes as parameter the "picture_serial_id" field to return me the picture in base64.

This is where I think the problem lies, during the second call to retrieve the dog's picture in base64, I add a new field to the dog object passed as reference during my request containing the picture in base64 that I called "base64_picture". Indeed, I want to display in my view this picture when it exists but unfortunately, the display is done before loading the picture in base64 in the new field "base64_picture".

*HTTP requests work well and the user data is also displayed very well.*

**template tag**

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <b-container>
      <b-row id="title" class="text-center">
        <b-col>
          <h1 class="font-weight-bold">Mes informations</h1>
        </b-col>
      </b-row>
      <b-row id="title">
        <b-col md="4" style="margin-bottom: 10px" class="text-center d-flex flex-column align-items-center text-center">
          <b-card
            style="padding: 10px; width: 100%"
            img-src="./../assets/img/user-profile.png"
            img-top
            :title="firstname"
          >
            <p class="text-secondary mb-1" v-if="code_role == '1'">Client</p>
            <p class="text-secondary mb-1">{{ address }}</p>
          </b-card>
        </b-col>
        <b-col md="8">
          <b-card style="margin-bottom: 10px">
            <b-row>
              <b-col sm="3">
                <h6 class="mb-0">Nom complet</h6>
              </b-col>
              <b-col sm="9" class="text-secondary">
                {{ firstname }} {{ lastname }}
              </b-col>
            </b-row>
            <hr />
            <b-row>
              <b-col sm="3">
                <h6 class="mb-0">Adresse e-mail</h6>
              </b-col>
              <b-col sm="9" class="text-secondary">{{ email }}</b-col>
            </b-row>
            <hr />
            <b-row>
              <b-col sm="3">
                <h6 class="mb-0">Numéro de téléphone</h6>
              </b-col>
              <b-col sm="9" class="text-secondary">{{ phonenumber }}</b-col>
            </b-row>
            <hr />
            <b-row>
              <b-col sm="3">
                <h6 class="mb-0">Adresse de domicile</h6>
              </b-col>
              <b-col sm="9" class="text-secondary">{{ address }}</b-col>
            </b-row>
          </b-card>
          <b-row>
            <b-col md="6" v-for="dog in dogs" :key="dog.id"> //
              <b-card :img-src="dog.base64_picture"> <!-- PROBLEM HERE -->
                <b-row>
                  <b-col sm="4">
                    <h6 class="mb-0">Nom</h6>
                  </b-col>
                  <b-col sm="8" class="text-secondary">{{ dog.name }}</b-col>
                </b-row>
                <hr />
                <b-row>
                  <b-col sm="4">
                    <h6 class="mb-0">Race</h6>
                  </b-col>
                  <b-col sm="8" class="text-secondary">{{ dog.breed }}</b-col>
                </b-row>
                <hr />
                <b-row>
                  <b-col sm="4">
                    <h6 class="mb-0">Sexe</h6>
                  </b-col>
                  <b-col sm="8" class="text-secondary">{{ dog.sex }}</b-col>
                </b-row>
                <hr />
                <b-row>
                  <b-col sm="4">
                    <h6 class="mb-0">Numéro de puce</h6>
                  </b-col>
                  <b-col sm="8" class="text-secondary">{{ dog.chip_id }}</b-col>
                </b-row>
              </b-card>
            </b-col>
          </b-row>
        </b-col>
      </b-row>
    </b-container>
  </div>
</template>
```

**script tag (initial problem)**

```js
export default {
  name: "CustomerInformation",
  data() {
    return {
      id: null,
      email: null,
      firstname: null,
      lastname: null,
      phonenumber: null,
      address: null,
      code_role: null,
      dogs: [],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    loadAuthCustomerInformations() {
      const config = {
        headers: {
          "Authorization" : this.$store.state.api_token
        },
      };
      this.$http
        .get("URL"+/users/me, config)
        .then((response) => {
          const vm = this;
          vm.$jquery.each(response.data.dogs, function (index, item) {
            if (item.picture_serial_id) {
              vm.loadDogPicture(item.picture_serial_id, item);
            }
          });
          vm.id = response.data.id;
          vm.email = response.data.email;
          vm.firstname = response.data.firstname;
          vm.lastname = response.data.lastname;
          vm.phonenumber = response.data.phonenumber;
          vm.address = response.data.address;
          vm.code_role = response.data.code_role;
          vm.dogs = response.data.dogs;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    },
    loadDogPicture(picture_serial_id, dog) {
      this.$http
        .get(
          "URL" + "/dogs/downloadPicture/" +
            picture_serial_id
        )
        .then((response) => {
          dog["base64_picture"] = response.data;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.loadAuthCustomerInformations();
  },
};
```

**template tag (ugly solution)**

```html
<template>
  <div v-if="!dataLoading">
    <!-- CONTENT -->
  </div>
</template>
```

**script tag (ugly solution)**

```js
export default {
  name: "CustomerInformation",
  data() {
    return {
      id: null,
      email: null,
      firstname: null,
      lastname: null,
      phonenumber: null,
      address: null,
      code_role: null,
      dogs: [],
      dataLoading: true,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    loadAuthCustomerInformations() {
      const config = {
        headers: {
          "Authorization" : this.$store.state.api_token
        },
      };
      this.$http
        .get("URL" + "/users/me/", config)
        .then((response) => {
          const vm = this;
          let url = "URL" + "dogs/downloadPicture/";
          let promisedEvents = [];
          vm.$jquery.each(response.data.dogs, function (index, item) {
            if (item.picture_serial_id) {
              promisedEvents.push(vm.$http.get(url + item.picture_serial_id));
            }
          });
          vm.id = response.data.id;
          vm.email = response.data.email;
          vm.firstname = response.data.firstname;
          vm.lastname = response.data.lastname;
          vm.phonenumber = response.data.phonenumber;
          vm.address = response.data.address;
          vm.code_role = response.data.code_role;
          vm.dogs = response.data.dogs;
          console.log(response);
          return Promise.all(promisedEvents);
        })
        .then((response) => {
          const vm = this;
          this.$jquery.each(response, function (index, item) {
            var parts = item.config.url.split("/");
            var picture_serial_id = parts[parts.length - 1];
            const dog = vm.dogs.find(element => element.picture_serial_id == picture_serial_id);
            dog["base64_picture"] = item.data;
            console.log(vm.dogs);
          });
          this.dataLoading = false;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.loadAuthCustomerInformations();
  },
};
```

I found a solution that I find very ugly, that's why I come to you to find a better way.

*I am a beginner with axios promises and this is my first vuejs app.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is not that ugly in my opinion. There are a couple of alternatives, depending on your aim for how you want the page to load. Your current solution will effectively not render anything on that page until everything is loaded.

An alternative would be to put your `v-if="!dataLoading"` into your img tag. Then the rest of your content would load while waiting for the image to be fetched.

You could put a placeholder image if you know what the dimensions of each image will be, so the layout won't jump around as the images load.